# RDS Mysql point in time restore fails - incompatible state

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, database-restore

I have an RDS MySQL instance with MySQL version 5.7.19 for which a point in time restore failed with a status of "incompatible-state".

Through experimentation I have determined that point in time restores fail up until the next snapshot taken and work immediately after the snapshot was taken.

AWS Support tells me that

> The restore operation encountered inserts/updates with strings
>   containing non-encoded binary characters which are a known source of
>   decoding issues. This issue is a terminal problem as it prevents us
>   from understanding where exactly the replay broke.

I'm trying to identify how to proactively mitigate the issue. Is there any log I could find such "non-encoded binary characters" proactively without doing a PIT restore? Or do I need to periodically do a restore and snapshot on failure to ensure I have a high amount of time periods covered by PIT restore?

**Update**

Restoring the snapshot from before the failed PITR shows this error log before running any queries against it:

```
2018-05-31T07:59:50.880143Z 0 [Warning] 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER' sql mode was not set.
2018-05-31T07:59:50.881641Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --secure-file-priv: Location is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2018-05-31T07:59:50.885191Z 0 [Note] /rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.19-log) starting as process 3470 ...
2018-05-31T07:59:51.126014Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2018-05-31T07:59:51.126054Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2018-05-31T07:59:51.126060Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2018-05-31T07:59:51.126064Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2018-05-31T07:59:51.126068Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2018-05-31T07:59:51.126071Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2018-05-31T07:59:51.150879Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2018-05-31T07:59:51.182600Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2018-05-31T07:59:51.184624Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 1G, instances = 8, chunk size = 128M
2018-05-31T07:59:51.245944Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2018-05-31T07:59:51.274809Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2018-05-31T07:59:51.661104Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2018-05-31T07:59:52.079538Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 205460220725
2018-05-31T07:59:53.616196Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 205460333516
2018-05-31T07:59:54.463445Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2018-05-31T07:59:54.463472Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2018-05-31T07:59:56.869876Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Transaction 1712897897 was in the XA prepared state.
2018-05-31T07:59:57.059082Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 1 transaction(s) which must be rolled back or cleaned up in total 0 row operations to undo
2018-05-31T07:59:57.059107Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Trx id counter is 1712898304
2018-05-31T07:59:57.060227Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percent: 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
2018-05-31T07:59:57.606094Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Apply batch completed
2018-05-31T07:59:57.606126Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Last MySQL binlog file position 0 7766, file name mysql-bin-changelog.196126
2018-05-31T08:01:05.616244Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting in background the rollback of uncommitted transactions
2018-05-31T08:01:05.616271Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of non-prepared transactions completed
2018-05-31T08:01:05.617146Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2018-05-31T08:01:05.617158Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2018-05-31T08:01:05.617203Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file '/rdsdbdata/db/innodb/ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2018-05-31T08:01:07.653103Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File '/rdsdbdata/db/innodb/ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2018-05-31T08:01:07.654148Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2018-05-31T08:01:07.654159Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2018-05-31T08:01:07.870099Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2018-05-31T08:01:07.920296Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.19 started; log sequence number 205460333516
2018-05-31T08:01:07.920583Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 76646ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=0 and evicted=0, during the time.)
2018-05-31T08:01:07.920723Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /rdsdbdata/db/innodb/ib_buffer_pool
2018-05-31T08:01:07.924167Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2018-05-31T08:01:07.938375Z 0 [Note] Recovering after a crash using /rdsdbdata/log/binlog/mysql-bin-changelog
2018-05-31T08:01:07.938453Z 0 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
2018-05-31T08:01:07.938489Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting recovery for XA transactions...
2018-05-31T08:01:07.938496Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Transaction 1712897897 in prepared state after recovery
2018-05-31T08:01:07.938500Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Transaction contains changes to 1 rows
2018-05-31T08:01:07.938504Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 1 transactions in prepared state after recovery
2018-05-31T08:01:07.938506Z 0 [Note] Found 1 prepared transaction(s) in InnoDB
2018-05-31T08:01:07.975797Z 0 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
2018-05-31T08:01:08.009971Z 0 [Note] Salting uuid generator variables, current_pid: 3470, server_start_time: 1527753590, bytes_sent: 0, 
2018-05-31T08:01:08.013725Z 0 [Note] Generated uuid: 'c65e1206-64a8-11e8-acdc-0642b77ee370', server_start_time: 976718170713733380, bytes_sent: 47057241759744
2018-05-31T08:01:08.013758Z 0 [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: c65e1206-64a8-11e8-acdc-0642b77ee370.
2018-05-31T08:01:08.044320Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2018-05-31T08:01:08.044373Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2018-05-31T08:01:08.044384Z 0 [Note] - '::' resolves to '::';
2018-05-31T08:01:08.044401Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2018-05-31T08:01:09.042028Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2018-05-31T08:01:09.042160Z 0 [Note] /rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.19-log' socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock' port: 3306 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2018-05-31T08:01:09.042169Z 0 [Note] Executing 'SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;' to get a list of tables using the deprecated partition engine. You may use the startup option '--disable-partition-engine-check' to skip this check. 
2018-05-31T08:01:09.042171Z 0 [Note] Beginning of list of non-natively partitioned tables
2018-05-31T08:01:09.889603Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 180531 8:01:09
2018-05-31T08:01:14.839437Z 0 [Note] End of list of non-natively partitioned tables
----------------------- END OF LOG ----------------------
```

A check for non InnoDB tables shows these:

```
+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------------+------------+--------+---------+------------+------------+----------------+-------------+------------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------------+---------------+
| TABLE_CATALOG | TABLE_SCHEMA            | TABLE_NAME                    | TABLE_TYPE | ENGINE | VERSION | ROW_FORMAT | TABLE_ROWS | AVG_ROW_LENGTH | DATA_LENGTH | MAX_DATA_LENGTH  | INDEX_LENGTH | DATA_FREE | AUTO_INCREMENT | CREATE_TIME         | UPDATE_TIME         | CHECK_TIME | TABLE_COLLATION    | CHECKSUM | CREATE_OPTIONS | TABLE_COMMENT |
+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------------+------------+--------+---------+------------+------------+----------------+-------------+------------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------------+---------------+
| def           | promosolutions_co_nz    | w90h1_finder_tokens           | BASE TABLE | MEMORY |      10 | Fixed      |          0 |            459 |           0 |         15040512 |            0 |         0 |           NULL | 2018-05-31 08:20:13 | NULL                | NULL       | utf8_general_ci    |     NULL |                |               |
| def           | promosolutions_co_nz    | w90h1_finder_tokens_aggregate | BASE TABLE | MEMORY |      10 | Fixed      |          0 |            474 |           0 |         15061350 |            0 |         0 |           NULL | 2018-05-31 08:20:13 | NULL                | NULL       | utf8_general_ci    |     NULL |                |               |
| def           | vc                      | CORE                          | BASE TABLE | MEMORY |      10 | Fixed      |          0 |            777 |           0 |         16627023 |            0 |         0 |           NULL | 2018-05-31 08:20:23 | NULL                | NULL       | latin1_swedish_ci  |     NULL |                |               |
| def           | vc                      | CORErs                        | BASE TABLE | MEMORY |      10 | Fixed      |          0 |            786 |           0 |         16649838 |            0 |         0 |           NULL | 2018-05-31 08:20:23 | NULL                | NULL       | latin1_swedish_ci  |     NULL |                |               |
| def           | vc                      | vw_mygroups                   | BASE TABLE | MyISAM |      10 | Fixed      |          0 |              0 |           0 | 1970324836974591 |         1024 |         0 |           NULL | 2018-05-01 04:44:19 | 2018-05-01 04:44:19 | NULL       | utf8_general_ci    |     NULL |                |               |
| def           | www_automatem_co_nz     | jos_finder_tokens             | BASE TABLE | MEMORY |      10 | Fixed      |          0 |            623 |           0 |         15553818 |            0 |         0 |           NULL | 2018-05-31 08:20:27 | NULL                | NULL       | utf8mb4_general_ci |     NULL |                |               |
| def           | www_automatem_co_nz     | jos_finder_tokens_aggregate   | BASE TABLE | MEMORY |      10 | Fixed      |          0 |            639 |           0 |         15582015 |            0 |         0 |           NULL | 2018-05-31 08:20:27 | NULL                | NULL       | utf8mb4_general_ci |     NULL |                |               |
| def           | www_bayautomotive_co_nz | jos_finder_tokens             | BASE TABLE | MEMORY |      10 | Fixed      |          0 |            623 |           0 |         15553818 |            0 |         0 |           NULL | 2018-05-31 08:20:28 | NULL                | NULL       | utf8mb4_general_ci |     NULL |                |               |
| def           | www_bayautomotive_co_nz | jos_finder_tokens_aggregate   | BASE TABLE | MEMORY |      10 | Fixed      |          0 |            639 |           0 |         15582015 |            0 |         0 |           NULL | 2018-05-31 08:20:28 | NULL                | NULL       | utf8mb4_general_ci |     NULL |                |               |
| def           | www_xpanda_co_nz        | jos_finder_tokens             | BASE TABLE | MEMORY |      10 | Fixed      |          0 |            623 |           0 |         15553818 |            0 |         0 |           NULL | 2018-05-31 08:20:36 | NULL                | NULL       | utf8mb4_general_ci |     NULL |                |               |
| def           | www_xpanda_co_nz        | jos_finder_tokens_aggregate   | BASE TABLE | MEMORY |      10 | Fixed      |          0 |            639 |           0 |         15582015 |            0 |         0 |           NULL | 2018-05-31 08:20:36 | NULL                | NULL       | utf8mb4_general_ci |     NULL |                |               |
+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------------+------------+--------+---------+------------+------------+----------------+-------------+------------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------------+---------------+
```

(don't worry, none of these are hosted by this server anymore)

I have run select * on all these tables (all empty) and inserted a singe record into each. The error log shows no additional entries in CloudWatch.

Comment: The response from support seems entirely unsatisfactory.  If point in time restores can randomly fail, the service has a fundamental defect that needs to be remedied.  If I were in your position, I would insist that the issue be escalated to someone who *can* understand exactly where the replay broke, and fix the underlying issue that makes this condition possible, or at minimum provide a much more thorough explanation of what isn't right.  It is, after all, a fully repeatable issue, so I'm taken aback by the response being offered. It's a managed service. You shouldn't be able to break it.

Comment: Tell me about it! Nevertheless, I'm hoping someone can tell me which log this would be in and I can find a way to stream it to Cloudwatch to get an Alert and Snapshot process build around this issue

Comment: That's the thing... there should be nothing for you to find, because the condition as described doesn't seem to involve something that's genuinely invalid, so it should not be one that can break things.  It sounds like an error that isn't an error until a restore is attempted.  Check two things, please: What does `SELECT @@BINLOG FORMAT;` report?  And does `SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE engine != 'InnoDB' AND table_schema NOT IN ('mysql','information_schema','performance_schema','sys');` find any of *your* tables? (no need to show this, just verify)

Comment: I've made assumptions that it may be one of these two things biting you, and answered accordingly.  Please keep us advised of your findings.

Comment: I suspected a MyISAm table would be the issue and I found a single one on  the server. However, testing a range of restore times when the table was in there and was removed showed that the issue was not related to a MyISAM table. It does restore after the snapshot, before the table is removed

Comment: I don't believe this is conclusive.  It's not the *presence* of the table, but rather the *state* of the table, on disk, at the instant the snapshot actually begins, that is potentially problematic.  RDS snapshots are EBS snapshots, so they resemble what you'd have on a conventional server if you just flushed and locked the tables in the mysql schema and unplugged the machine.  When it came back, InnoDB crash recovery would fix any InnoDB inconsistencies, and the mysql schema would be fine because it was locked in a flushed state, but other MyISAM tables could be corrupt.

Comment: If you still have the snapshot that began the time window where PITR wasn't viable, create a new instance from that snapshot (not a specific point in time, just from the snapshot) and when it comes up, see if you can successfully select from and then write to that MyISAM table.  Verify that it works and that there is nothing mentioned about it in the error log.  If it throws an error about the table being crashed, that's a smoking gun, indicating that the table was not captured in a stable state when the snapshot occurred.

Comment: Have updated question with details from snapshot restore. It still would be good to be able to reproduce problem

Comment: I completely agree, it would be great to be able to reproduce the problem... but it looks like the unsupported storage engine theory has now been ruled out.  If RDS is improperly handling binary payloads during log playback, there really isn't a way for you to reproduce it, because it's a problem with RDS infrastructure components that you can't access.  If you had been capturing your binary logs external to RDS (mysqlbinlog can do this), you could confirm whether any such payloads can be found in the logs, which would at least allow you to confirm whether the assertion is credible.

Comment: ...but if that's the issue, setting `binlog_format` to `ROW` *should* eliminate it as a possibility, because playback of row images uses base64 encoding so that all the binary payload is handled as proper character data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the instance's parameter group, set `binlog_format` to `ROW`.  The default on RDS is `MIXED` even though there is not a compelling reason for this default value under a majority of conditions.  In my systems, `ROW` is always used because it has substantial advantages over `MIXED`.

One of the more compelling reasons in this scenario is this part of the explanation:

> The restore operation encountered inserts/updates with strings containing non-encoded binary characters

While this does not strike me as a complete explanation (because this is not actually invalid, absent a bug) we can easily avoid the problem as described -- the `ROW` logging format captures changed row images, instead of capturing insert/update(/delete) statements as "strings," so if there is a problem with the way either the RDS infrastructure or the underlying MySQL version handles these, this should eliminate it.

The `MIXED` mode allows the optimizer to choose whether to log the results of DML as the query that was issued or as images of the rows that were changed, and it will tend to log the statement if nothing internally flags the statement as non-deterministic for, or otherwise incompatible with, replay -- such as using things like the `UUID()` function (which would not generate the same value when invoked, in the future).  (Other functions, like `NOW()` have add-on mechanisms built into the logging that make them deterministic for replay, counter-intuitively.)

The only meaningful caveat that comes to mind with `ROW` mode is that your tables must all have primary keys (which should be standard practice, anyway) else restoration and replication (if you have replicas) can be slower, since the entire table is scanned for deletes and updates in that condition... but setting that one consideration aside, the advantages of `ROW` based logging are such that I have not had occasion to use anything other than `ROW` for many years.

The second issue is to ensure than you are not using MyISAM or any other storage engines, except for the system tables that use them by default (do not try to change those).

MyISAM does not have InnoDB's crash recovery capability, and RDS relies on this capability to make snapshots usable.  It takes precautions on the system tables, so they don't pose an issue, but for your tables, no protection is in place.  A non-MyISAM table that is not in a safely coalesced state when the snapshot occurs may prevent the snapshot from working properly.

While support did not identify this as being your issue, it is consistent with your observation that point-in-time does not work until you create a new snapshot.

Although undocumented in any detail, my assumption based on anecdotal evidence is that point-in-time starts with the snapshot before but closest in time to the desired recovery point, and then applies all the relevant archived binary logs to play-forward to the desired recovery point.  That's how you do it manually, outside of RDS, and based on the observable actions of the "rdsadmin" user, there's not a reason to believe that RDS reinvented the wheel.

Of course, the trouble with a snapshot that includes mangled MyISAM tables is, this isn't something that presents itself until *after* you restore the snapshot *and* then try to access one of the tables.

If this is actually the issue, support may have assumed that you were aware of the following and uncorrectly ruled it out as a possibility:

> The MyISAM storage engine does not support reliable recovery and can result in lost or corrupt data when MySQL is restarted after a recovery, preventing Point-In-Time restore or snapshot restore from working as intended.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_MySQL.html

If you are using MyISAM tables, you should convert those to InnoDB.

Comment: Ok, firstly confirming I have MIXED format set at this moment. This all makes sense to me. I'm happy to try this, but it would be great if I could reproduce the failed PIT restore in a consistent way. How would i get insert those invalid characters?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Web Services has further researched this issue and has found the culprit as follows:

```
********* update from service team ***********

This is decoded DDL in the binary log that blocked point-in-time restore for restore-markovina-aws-support. It is a "create table if not exists" for the drsarahhart_com.wp_wfBlocks7 table. I had to manually skip it (as the table already existed) to push the restore to completion (there was also a similar DDL in a later binary log).

# at 375050
#180523 19:10:46 server id 153211832  end_log_pos 375115 CRC32 0x1eec997a       Anonymous_GTID  last_committed=301      sequence_number=302     rbr_only=no
SET @@SESSION.GTID_NEXT= 'ANONYMOUS'/*!*/;
# at 375115
#180523 19:10:46 server id 153211832  end_log_pos 375785 CRC32 0xc43c076b       Query   thread_id=584850        exec_time=0     error_code=0
SET TIMESTAMP=1527102646/*!*/;
create table IF NOT EXISTS wp_wfBlocks7 (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `IP` binary(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT '\^@\^@\^@\^@\^@\^@\^@\^@\^@\^@\^@\^@\^@\^@\^@\^@',
  `blockedTime` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `reason` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `lastAttempt` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `blockedHits` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `expiration` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `parameters` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `type` (`type`),
  KEY `IP` (`IP`),
  KEY `expiration` (`expiration`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
/*!*/;
# at 375785

The problematic characters were in the sequence: '\^@\^@\^@\^@\^@\^@\^@\^@\^@\^@\^@\^@\^@\^@\^@\^@'
This corresponds to this ASCII code point sequence: 5c 27 5c 00 5c 00 5c 00 5c 00 5c 00 5c 00 5c 00 5c 00 5c 00 5c 00 5c 00 5c 00 5c 00 5c 00 5c 00 27 00

How is the customer executing the DDL in the first place to create this table? Is the DDL being auto-generated or is someone running a script? If using a script how are they encoding the script contents? 

********* end update from service team ********
```

I'm pretty sure this is a table created by Wordpress WordFence plugin, I will check if this is still current and report back here.

Comment: Clearly the intended value is `\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0`, 16 bytes of ASCII `NUL`...  `NUL` can be represented as `\0` in MySQL, and is seen elsewhere represented as `^@`... but `\^@` seems like a hybrid of the two.  Something clearly has a bug, though -- as noted, "how is the customer executing the DDL in the first place" is very much a valid question, because either you are actually sending a malformed query (which should not be working -- that's a bug), or you aren't and the bug is somewhere deeper.  Good to see that they did actually provide you with some technical details, though.